# Prove that $A = \dfrac{f^2(1)+f^2(-1)}{2}$ is a composite number

Tags: number-theory

> Given $f(x) = a^{2016}x^2+bx+a^{2016}c-1$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$, suppose that the equation $f(x) = -2$ has two positive integer solutions. Prove that $A = \dfrac{f(1)^2+f(-1)^2}{2}$ is a composite number.

Let $g(x) = f(x)-2 = a^{2016}x^2+bx+a^{2016}c-3$, and let $-r,-s$ be the two positive integer roots of $g(x)$. Then by Vieta's Formula, $r+s = \dfrac{b}{a^{2016}}$ and $rs = \dfrac{a^{2016}c-3}{a^{2016}}$. Thus $a = \pm 1$ and so $f(x) = x^2+bx+c-1$ and so $f(1) = b+c$ and $f(-1) = c-b$. Then $$A = \dfrac{[(b+c)^2+b(b+c)+c-1]+[(c-b)^2+b(c-b)+c-1]}{2} = b^2+bc+c^2+c-1.$$ How do we prove this is composite?

Comment: You have used that $f(x)=2$ has two solutions.  You have not used that $f(x)=2$ has two *integer* solutions.

Comment: @user19405892: I don't get it: you have changed the equation into $f(x) = -2$, but all the other calculations are done for $f(x) = 2$. Which one is the correct sign? Furthermore, is $f^2 (1) = (f \circ f) (1)$?

Answer (score 1):

The claim is not true: taking $a=1, \ b=2, \ c=3$, the equation $f(x) - 2 = 0$ is $x^2 + 2x = 0$, having both roots integers ($0$ and $-2$), but $A = \dfrac {5^2 + 1^2} 2 = 13$, clearly not a composite number.

Comment: I found the problem here: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u331859h1362227p7468353. Does the question there mean something else?

Comment: @user19405892: The problem could simply be wrong. Unfortunately, I am not registered on that forum, so I have no way of contacting the author of this problem. If you are, then send please them my counterexample and comments.

Comment: @user19405892: I have created an account on AoPS and have posted my comments there. Let's see what the author answers.

Comment: I think $f^2$ here might mean composition, rather than $(f(1))^2$. In that case, the counterexample won't work.

Comment: I changed the question.

Comment: $-2$ is not a positive root - so this counter example does not count.

Comment: @johannesvalks: Pfff... Then just take $b=-2$, and the equation becomes $x^2 - 2x =0$, with the roots $0$ and $2$ positive. My objection remains relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing $ a = 1$, $b = -3$, $c = 5$ gives two positive integer roots to $f(x) = 2$ ($x = 1$ and $x = 2$) and $[f^2(1)+f^2(-1)]/2 = 23$. This statement appears to be false.

If $f^2(x)$ means $f(x)^2$, then the statement fails for $a =1$, $b = -6$, $c = 11$, where the two roots are 2 and 4 and $[f(1)^2+f(-1)^2]/2 = 157$.

Comment: In this case $f(1)=2$ and $f(-1)=8$ so $[2^2+8^2]/2=34$ and not $23$...

Comment: @johannesvalks In the first example I'm interpreting $f^2(x)$ to mean $f(f(x))$.